# Trace of the inverse of different ideal

Tags: algebraic-number-theory

Let $L/K$ be a finite extension of number field, we can define the different ideal as the inverse of the fractional ideal $B=\{x \in L |\operatorname{Tr}(xO_L) \subseteq O_K \}$, so we have $\operatorname{Tr}B \subseteq O_K$. Does it always holds that $\operatorname{Tr}B = O_K$?  If not, how to compute the index $\left[ O_K:\operatorname{Tr} B\right]$? Does this number reflects the ramification of L/K?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose $\text{Tr}(B)$ was a proper ideal $I$ of $O_K$. Consider $I^{-1}B$. The trace of everything in $I^{-1}B$ then lies in $O_K$. Also $I^{-1}B$ is a fractional ideal of $O_L$, so $\text{Tr}(yI^{-1}B)\subseteq O_K$ for all $y\in O_L$. Therefore $I^{-1}B\subseteq B$ which is false. So
$\text{Tr}(B)=O_K$.

Comment: Why $\text{Tr}(yI^{-1}B)\subseteq O_K$ for every $y$ in $O_L$  when we only know  $\text{Tr}(I^{-1}B)\subseteq O_K$?

Comment: @ZhiyuZhang Because $yI^{-1}B\subseteq I^{-1}B$.